# asking about pc3l-12800s if it works with my HP Zbook 15 G2

Tags: laptop, memory

i want to ask about my laptop HP Zbook 15 G2.
i have ram of 8GB 2Rx8 PC3L - 12800 S and when i put it in my laptop it doesn't work, doesn't boot at all ( stay off ).

i want to ask if this laptop support those pc3l-12800s rams or just the rams doesn't work though it's brand new.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to HP that model supports only PC3L, 12800, 1600-MHz memory, 4 or 8gb sticks.

http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=6978814&docId=emr_na-c04503657&docLocale=en_US#N10013

Memory "compatibility" is another issue, because the general specs are correct it may not work, I suggest looking at the following sites that guarantee compatibility.

http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/homepage

http://www.kingston.com/us/